# I am supposed to find the sum of any two numbers in list that gives the result 16.But it says list index out of range.What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python-3.x

I expect it to print 'Sum is possible' but I get error!

```
list = [2,4,7,3,9]
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(list)+1):
        if list[i]+list[j]==16:
            print("Sum is possible")
```

Comment: Why did you write iterate j in `range(i+1,len(list) + 1)`, it should be only until `len(list)` , and if you are doing this for a coding exercise your solution is N-squared while it can be solved in NlgN

Comment: `list` is a native object name in python. Use the convention in this case which consists of naming your `list` with an appended underscore, `_`,  i.e. `list_`.

Comment: len(list)+1?  The +1 is "out of range".

Comment: Oh now it works fine!My bad!I just forgot that in range(x),it loops 1 less.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code , the range of the index j is [i+1,len(list)+1] which will be [i+1,5] for each i since list is a list with length 5.
list[5] will throw index out of range error, change your 3rd line to

```
for j in range(i+1,len(list)):
```

should work.